# Save new field in custom post type taxonomy

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I added an upload image to my custom post type taxonomy. Post type is `portfolio`, and taxonomy is `portfolio-category`.

The input field, and adding of the image (opening the wordpress uploader) works. However, since I've basically copied this from my category (regular posts), some options are not saving. I've added my form fields like this:

```
//Category image
if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_image_category_field' ) ){
    function mytheme_image_category_field( $tag ) {
        $t_id = $tag->term_id;
        $cat_meta = get_option("category_$t_id");
        ?>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="extra1"><?php esc_attr_e('Featured Image', 'mytheme'); ?></label></th>
            <?php print_r($cat_meta, true); ?>
            <td>
                <div class="portfolio_category_image">
                <?php if(isset($cat_meta['taxonomy_portfolio_category_image']) && $cat_meta['taxonomy_portfolio_category_image']!=''): ?>
                <img width="254" src="<?php echo esc_url($cat_meta['taxonomy_portfolio_category_image']);?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="portfolio_category_image_upload" name="Cat_meta[taxonomy_portfolio_category_image]" value="<?php (isset($cat_meta['taxonomy_portfolio_category_image']) && $cat_meta['taxonomy_portfolio_category_image']!='') ? esc_attr_e($cat_meta['taxonomy_portfolio_category_image']) : '' ;?>">
                <input type="button" class="button portfolio_upload_image_button" name="image_upload" value=" <?php esc_attr_e('Upload Image', 'mytheme');?>">
                <input type="button" class="button portfolio_remove_image_button" name="remove_image_upload" value=" <?php esc_attr_e('Remove Image', 'mytheme');?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
}

add_action ( 'portfolio-category_edit_form_fields', 'mytheme_image_category_field');

if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_extra_add_image_upload_field' ) ){
    function mytheme_extra_add_image_upload_field( $tag ) {
        $t_id = (is_object($tag)) ? $tag->term_id:'';
        $cat_meta = get_option("category_$t_id");
        ?>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="extra1"><?php esc_attr_e('Featured Image', 'mytheme'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="portfolio_category_image_upload" name="Cat_meta[taxonomy_portfolio_category_image]" value="<?php echo (isset($cat_meta['taxonomy_portfolio_category_image']) && $cat_meta['taxonomy_portfolio_category_image'] != '') ? esc_attr($cat_meta['taxonomy_portfolio_category_image']) : '' ;?>">
            <input type="button" class="button portfolio_upload_image_button" name="Cat_meta[taxonomy_portfolio_category_image]" value=" <?php esc_attr_e('Upload Image', 'mytheme');?>">
            <input type="button" class="button portfolio_remove_image_button" name="remove_image_upload" value=" <?php esc_attr_e('Remove Image', 'mytheme');?>">
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action ( 'portfolio-category_add_form_fields', 'mytheme_extra_add_image_upload_field');
```

The clear problem is that in custom post types I'm not writing anything in `wp_options` table so `$cat_meta = get_option("category_$t_id");` won't get anything.

What I get when I echo `$t_id` is my term id. So I know I need to use `terms` in some way to save my options. But here is where I'm stuck. `get_terms('portfolio-category')` will correctly output every term I have, but I don't have my uploaded image in there.

The javascript is (if anyone needs to test it):

```
$(document).on('click', '.portfolio_upload_image_button', portfolio_upload_image_button);

function portfolio_upload_image_button(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $input_field = $(this).prev();
    var $image = $('.portfolio_category_image');
    var custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Add Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Add Image'
        },
        multiple: false
    });
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $input_field.val(attachment.url);
        $image.html('<img width="254" src="'+attachment.url+'" />');
    });
    custom_uploader.open();
}

$(document).on('click', '.portfolio_remove_image_button', portfolio_remove_image_button);

function portfolio_remove_image_button(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $input_field = $('.portfolio_category_image_upload');
    var $image = $('.portfolio_category_image');

    $input_field.val('');
    $image.html('');
}
```

This works for my regular posts, but doesn't for my CPT.

**EDIT**

Should I use [wp_insert_term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term)? To update my taxonomy terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I followed [this](http://wpthemetutorial.com/2013/02/21/adding-custom-meta-to-wordpress-taxonomies/) and [this](http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-custom-meta-taxonomies) post and I figured it out.

```
class Category_Taxonomy_Image{

    function __construct(){

        add_action( 'portfolio-category_add_form_fields', array( $this, 'add_tax_image_field' ) );
        add_action( 'portfolio-category_edit_form_fields', array( $this, 'edit_tax_image_field' ) );
        // saving
        add_action( 'edited_portfolio-category', array( $this, 'save_tax_meta' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'create_portfolio-category', array( $this, 'save_tax_meta' ), 10, 2 );

    }

    public function add_tax_image_field(){
    ?>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="term_meta[tax_image]"><?php esc_html_e('Category Featured Image', 'mytheme'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="portfolio_category_image_upload" name="term_meta[tax_image]" id="term_meta[tax_image]" value="" />
            <input type="button" class="button portfolio_upload_image_button" name="image_upload" value=" <?php esc_attr_e('Upload Image', 'mytheme');?>">
            <input type="button" class="button portfolio_remove_image_button" name="remove_image_upload" value=" <?php esc_attr_e('Remove Image', 'mytheme');?>">
            <p class="description"><?php esc_html_e('Add URL to image for the category image', 'mytheme'); ?></p>
        </div><!-- /.form-field -->
    <?php
    }

    public function edit_tax_image_field( $term ){
        $term_id = $term->term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$term_id" );
        $image = $term_meta['tax_image'] ? $term_meta['tax_image'] : '';
    ?>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row">
                <label for="term_meta[tax_image]"><?php esc_html_e('Category Featured Image', 'mytheme'); ?></label>
                <td>
                    <div class="portfolio_category_image">
                    <?php if(isset($image) && $image!=''): ?>
                        <img width="254" src="<?php echo esc_url($image);?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="portfolio_category_image_upload" name="term_meta[tax_image]" id="term_meta[tax_image]" value="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" />
                    <input type="button" class="button portfolio_upload_image_button" name="image_upload" value=" <?php esc_attr_e('Upload Image', 'mytheme');?>">
                    <input type="button" class="button portfolio_remove_image_button" name="remove_image_upload" value=" <?php esc_attr_e('Remove Image', 'mytheme');?>">
                    <p class="description"><?php esc_html_e('Add URL to image for the category image', 'mytheme'); ?></p>
                </td>
            </th>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }

    public function save_tax_meta( $term_id ){
        if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {
            $t_id = $term_id;
            $term_meta = array();
            $term_meta['tax_image'] = isset ( $_POST['term_meta']['tax_image'] ) ? esc_url( $_POST['term_meta']['tax_image'] ) : '';
            update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
        }
    }

}

$cat_tax_image = new Category_Taxonomy_Image();
```

The key was saving them to the `wp_options` table and adding to correct hook. Mainly:

```
add_action( '{custom-taxonomy-name}_add_form_fields', 'add_new_custom_fields');
add_action( '{custom-taxonomy-name}_edit_form_fields', 'add_edit_custom_fields');
```

And

```
add_action( 'create_{custom-taxonomy-name}', 'save_custom_taxonomy_meta');
add_action( 'edited_{custom-taxonomy-name}', 'save_custom_taxonomy_meta');
```